# Intercepting DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation

Please i'm really not a coder.

I need to intercept when a child is append to a div.

like this exemple (without timeout):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#holder').append('<div id="device">Test</div>');}, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="holder">
    <!––child dynamicly inserted-->
  </div>
</body>
```

I use mutationobserver but seams appear deprecated... I saw proxy() but i don't know how use it...

My mutation observer code:

```
  MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {  

        if ($('#main-view div.row').next().length != 0 ){
            DelRow();
        };

        $('#main-view div.row.divider .span4').toggleClass('span4 tile');

    });
});

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if (!isMobile){ 
        observer.observe(targetedNode, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
```

But don't work on mobile..

Comment: What have you tried with `Mutation Observer ` ?

Comment: Mutation Observer appears to still be available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I do this with mutation
  
  observerMutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) { 
$('#main-view').contents().removeClass('container').toggleClass('container-fluid');

  $('#main-view div.row.divider .span4').toggleClass('span4 tile');

 });
});
  
  Seams to be observer() deprecated. But i'm really not able to say if it's the same thing... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Answer (score 0):

Mutation observer works very well and is NOT deprecated. I use it all the time. Here's an example that listens for events and then alerts whether or not a div was added or subtracted. Try your best to apply the techniques in this demo to your own use case.

```
<div id="holder">
  <h2>Let's Add Div's Dynamically</h2>
</div>

<button id="button" type="button">Add New Div</button>

<script>
    const btn = $('#button');
    const holder = $('#holder');

    // append a new div to out holder element
    function addDiv(){
        holder.append('<div>A Great New Div!! :D</div>'); 
    }

    // attach click function to btn
    btn.click(addDiv);



    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
        $(mutationsList).each(function(index, item){
            if (item.type === 'childList'){

                if (item.addedNodes.length > 0){
                    alert('new div is being added!');
                }

                if (item.removedNodes.length > 0){
                    alert('div has been removed'); 
                }

            }
        });
    });

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(holder[0], { 
        attributes: true, 
        childList: true, 
        subtree: true 
    });
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mgf5eh1q/)

Comment: If i just use this, it told me: TypeError: Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object. If i listen document (observer.observe(document , ...), it work...

Comment: Your comment does not make sense to me. If it works, great! If it does not work, post _all necessary code_ so I can look.

Comment: Yes i understand. I can post the code, but it's not mine. This is the project: https://github.com/domoticz/domoticz/blob/0046914e3d9ba52e0a404629f591d39767fa4312/www/index.html#L1362 i juste want to know, when a child is add to #main-view

Comment: Can i right a code, how say 'if a child div #dashcontent is added to div #main-view" (or #holder) ?

Comment: And mutationobserver is not deprecated, but observe() seams to be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe